# Issue passing in a DataRow Type using Ref within C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm iterating through a DataTable using a "for" or "foreach" loop, I then attempt to pass the DataRow into another method using "Ref" to reference the row I need to modify. However, I then see the following error:

> A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter

I'd like to pass the DataRow into my method, as this negates further code blocks to update the original DataTable. Is this possible?

I've tried the following:

```
// Build request
for(int x = 0; x < (dt.Rows.Count -1); x++)
{
    if (dt.Rows[x]["FieldData"].ToString().Trim() == "Value")
    {
        // Do work
        DoWork.BuildRequest(ref dt.Rows[x], ref Result);
    }
}
```

And:

```
// Build request
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["FieldData"].ToString().Trim() == "Value")
    {
        // Do work
        DoWork.BuildRequest(ref row, ref Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what `ref` is doing here. You don't need it as you don't need to change the *instance* of the object you are passing, you're just modifying it's internal properties.

Comment: _"as this negates further code blocks to update the original DataTable"_ seems like you are trying to abuse `ref`, [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) the `DataTable` if you don't want updates while iterating

Comment: I pass it using ref as it calls a method from another class. I want to modify the original row being passed into that method without having to return the DataRow and writing more code to update the original row within the DataTable. I thought ref would be the best case to use.

Comment: Surely passing in a DataRow into the method (without the ref) wouldn't allow me to modify the original row? Correct me if I'm wrong please. Also thank you guys for helping

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the ref is most likely unnecessary. Classes are passed by reference already, only if the type 'Result' is a **structure** that is being modified by DoWork.BuildRequest would you need the ref keyword (as they are copied by value and values changed would not propagate up the call stack). Removing for clarity would probably be the best choice. But if you can't or this is code whose signature you can't change you can take a local reference and pass that.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  if (row["FieldData"].ToString().Trim() == "Value")
  {
    var dr = row;
    // Do work
    DoWork.BuildRequest(ref dr, ref Result);
  }
}
```